# SQL: How to reference another table's value in a CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to create a certain database about activities involving specific rooms and specific students. Something like, one activity takes place in up to 4 rooms (D, E, F ang G), but the students involved in the activity can obviously be in only one room.

So, I've created a table ROOMS, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ROOMS (
activityID int REFERENCES ACTIVITY(activityID) PRIMARY KEY
,Room char(1) CHECK(Room in ('D','E','F','G'))
);
```

Now I have to create table Students, which needs to say which rooms the students will be in.
However, say the user assigns rooms D and E, how do I create such constraint for the students table that takes in account for the rooms selected in the other table?

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: SQL Server, sorry, I'm not very familiar with these things

Comment: Sounds like a `StudentRooms` junction table is called for.

Comment: How does that work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SQL-Server or your project but based on information I think a many to many relationship is the best solution for your problem.